# How to see what the rendered React component looks like in the Jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run a test for the React component. I need to check how it looks like after rendering. Tried to use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` but it fails. Here is the code:

```
import { NewRec } from '../src/components/edit';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react/lib/ReactWithAddons';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

jest.mock('react-dom');
jest.mock('react/lib/ReactDefaultInjection');

describe('NewRec component', () => {
    const component = shallow(<NewRec />);
    it('returns true if blah blah', ()=>{
        var htmlstring = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<component />);
    });
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: There is no registered component for the tag component
```

I tried to call it like: `var htmlstring = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component);` then I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: renderToString(): You must pass a valid ReactElement.
```

Does anyone knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [snapshot feature](http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/07/27/jest-14.html) in Jest where it stores the rendered tree as a file. Note that you have to install [enzyme-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-to-json) as well to convert the enzyme rendered component to something the snapshot method can understand.

```
import { NewRec } from '../src/components/edit';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

describe('NewRec component', () = > {
  it('returns true if blah blah', () = > {
    const component = shallow(<NewRec />);
    expect(shallowToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This will create a new file in `__snapshot__` folder in your test folder, where you can inspect the rendered result. Every time you rerun the test, the component will be tested against the snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use enzyme, you can use Facebook's `react-test-renderer` too, it's even simpler:

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

test("Test 1", () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <TestItem />
  );

  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```